# Using tensorflow_transform with tensorflow 2.0

Tags: tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-transform

After installing tensorflow 2 and tensorflow_transform, when importing tensorflow_transform I get the error: 
    `from tensorflow.contrib.boosted_trees.python.ops import gen_quantile_ops
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.contrib'`

So it seems that tensorflow_transform is not yet on tf2. What is a work around for this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

All currently released versions of tensorflow-transform don't support TF 2.0.
See this table here: https://github.com/tensorflow/transform/blob/master/README.md#compatible-versions

The latest release of tensorflow-transform (0.14) only supports TF 1.14.

The team is currently working on TF 2.0 support in future releases.